# JMeter Recording - All actions cannot be performed

Tags: jmeter, proxy-server

While recording a workflow through JMeter proxy, I am not able to click some items(like buttons), which otherwise are available when the website is getting loaded without JMeter proxy.

Now, needless to say, i have to click those buttons to perform certain activities essential as a part of the workflow whose performance I want to measure.
I am quite new to JMeter, so not sure how to proceed with the problem. Is there any Proxy settings i should change?

When I am checking the website source there is no difference between the page getting loaded via proxy and the page without it.

Please let me know if additional info is required. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: All the resources of the page (scripts) are stored in the same server? the server(s) are using HTTPS ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check *jmeter.log* file (usually lives in JMeter's "bin" folder or folder, you launched JMeter from if it's different) for anything suspicious. Log file should be the first place to look into as JMeter basically writes anything there.

   You can increase verbosity if required by adding the next line to *user.properties* file (again lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   log_level.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy=DEBUG
   ```
2. Try [cleaning your browser history](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000510.htm), it's better to delete everything, especially cache.
3. Try re-installing JMeter certificate. See **Installing the JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder (was: HTTP Proxy Server )](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) for instructions

If above steps won't help and you're absolutely sure you're doing everything right you can try [raising a JMeter issue](http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

Also be aware of [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension) which is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test which doesn't require proxy server.